# "Walk/Don't Walk" street sign wired into bathroom light

Tags: electrical, switch, light-fixture

I have a game room type area that has it's own bathroom.  Above the door to the bathroom I would like to place one of those "Walk/Don't Walk" street signs.  I would like the "Don't Walk" to be wired so that it comes on with the light in the bathroom.  I would like the "Walk" to come on when the light in the bathroom goes off.  I was thinking a two way switch could do this ... but now I'm thinking that it wouldn't work.  Do you know which kind of switch I would need?

Comment: I don't know if you already have the light or just plan to get one, but make sure you verify that it will take "regular" household voltage (110V or 220V, depending on your location). I don't know anything about traffic lights but street lights can have quite high voltages.

Comment: 120 VAC printed on back.  I have verified that each side of the light works with household current.  Instead of one lamp for each side, each side has a lot of tiny LED bulbs.

Answer (score 4):

A 2 ways switch should totally do it:

- wire the common of the switch with the line cable
- wire one of the switch ways to the bathroom light and the don't walk light
- wire the other switch way to the walk light
- wire all lights second wire to the neutral cable
- if your walk/don't walk sign has a metal frame, wire it to the protective earth cable

Just ensure that:

- the bathroom light and don't walk light are connected in parallel, not in series
- your 2 ways switch is graded for the sum of your two lights (look at the number of watts on the bulbs)

You may want to add a second switch somewhere so the walk sign won't stay on 24/7 while the gaming room is empty (perhaps wiring everything to the main light switch off the gaming room?)

EDIT: I should add that, since it implies live electric current, YOU SHOULD HAVE A FULLY QUALIFIED PROFESSIONAL CHECKING YOUR DESIGN BEFORE YOU DO ANYTHING, and CHECKING WHAT YOU'VE DONE BEFORE ANY CONNECTION TO YOUR POWER GRID! (depending where you live, this may be mandatory by law; if it's not, you should still do it)

Or in other words, you do as you want, but I'm not responsible if anything goes wrong after you followed instruction from "some guy on the internet".